# Azure API Management - Authentication: OAuth2 vs Certificate

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management, client-certificates

I would like to have your mind about an implementation. Thank you in advance for any suggestion :)

**Scenario**
I have a set of APIs. They are accessible via REST and protected by OAuth2. I have also a list of machines that needs to access them. 
Question
On machine’s side, which is the best solution to access them? Should I implement a client certificate authentication or OAuth2 is a suitable solution?

**My doubts:**

- In case of hundreds, thousands of machines, the certificate
  management become too complex/costly?
- Should I use a certificate for each machine or one certificate for more than one?
- How can I deploy smartly the certificate to each machine?

I like the idea to have the mutual authentication, but I’m afraid is to heavy to maintain compared to the OAuth structure. I plan to use Microsoft Azure as cloud service.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the important factors here are client identity and privilege:

- You may have many client machines
- But do they represent a single identity, eg a cluster?
- And do they all have the same privilege?

By default I would aim for a solution where all client machines with the same privilege present the same credential / identity. The APIs can then authorize requests based on the client identity, provided in the access token.

The standard OAuth solution is Client Credentials flow, where clients each send a secret to the server.

If required (and supported by your Authorization Server) you can use a Mutual TLS form of Client Credentials, via the [Client Assertion Profile](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523#section-3.2). This usually boils down to a private key signature sent by the client, which is contained in a whitelist configured on the Authorization Server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try to follow your suggestions and i'll see what happens.